# when to use inbuild java http server or Jetty server

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, httpserver

I am working on a small java project, where I have to expose a web service and receive data from `soap ui`, So  I'm not able to understand which server to use to publish the web service. Now I'm using the inbuilt `java http server`, and my code is something like below:

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/testWs", new SayHello());
```

and this is working just fine, can someone please explain **when** to use `jetty server`(or any other server) and when to use inbuilt http server and **why?**